# index.jsp is not getting populated while running on the server

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am having a very annoying problem, I am creating dynamic project in java. I have two file 1) index.html 2)dataTable.jsp. both the file have simple hello world code. when I am running index.html it is running on localhost, while dataTable.jsp has also the same hello world content but its not running on local host. I am just getting white screen and no error message on console instead the server has started.
**This is directory structure**
[image]
**This is index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello from html</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is dataTable.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>dataTable</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello data table</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

when ever I am creating 'jsp' file its not running. so I created a html file and it worked.
I am really confuse why this is happening.

Comment: Can you please provide content of web.xml ? May be some problem with that.

Comment: @Paritosh  <display-name>DataTable</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>dataTable.jsp</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

Comment: Are you putting it in WEB-INF or WEB-INF/lib, as per snapshot looks under lib, if this is the case please put in WEB-INF

Comment: @Paritosh both files are under WEB-INF. they are not under lib

Comment: @Paritosh I made the change, Cleaned the project, republish, restarted the server but still same problem

Comment: what is the error info ? @varun

Comment: @ChenZhongPu I have mentioned in the question please check.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are putting Web.xml in WEB-INF/lib, if this is the case please put it in WEB-INF directory.

Comment: I made the change, Cleaned the project, republish, restarted the server but still same problem

Comment: what is your URL for running this jsp?

Comment: You should use localhost:8080/DataTable/dataTable.jsp, ...per your directory structure.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /DataTable/dataTable.jsp
since the files are in WEB-INF

Comment: That I'm saying put index.html and dataTable.jsp in webcomponent and web.xml in WEB-INF. Then use the above url, it will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75728/discussion-between-paritosh-and-varun).